# How to count specific numbers in massive on Python (not list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, massive

I have a program which generates random numbers from -10 to 10. My task is to count how many elements from 1 to 5 are in this massive. the problem is that I can't use functions like counter or others because `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` . Which functions can i use to fix it?

```
import random

for i in range(51):
    a = random.randint(-10, 10)
print(a)
```

Comment: "the problem is that I can't use functions like counter or others because `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`."  ----> You absolutely **can** use Counter. Apparently you tried to use Counter but there was an error in your code. Since you didn't post your code, we don't know what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, which sums `1` if the random `int` is in range from `1` to `5`, and this runs for `51` times. Finally, this sum is printed.

```
import random

print(sum(1 for i in range(51) if random.randint(-10, 11) in range(1, 5)))
```

The above segment is equivalent to:

```
import random

a = 0
for i in range(51):
    if random.randint(-10, 11) in range(1, 5):
        a += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely **can** use `collections.Counter` for this:

```py
import random
import collections
c = collections.Counter(random.randint(-10, 11) for i in range(51))
print(c)
# Counter({-9: 7, 10: 7, -5: 5, 8: 3, 1: 3, -10: 3, -4: 3, -7: 3, 5: 3, 0: 3, -3: 2, 6: 2, 4: 2, 9: 2, 3: 1, -6: 1, 2: 1})
n = sum(c[i] for i in range(1,6))  # number of elements between 1 and 5
print(n)
# 10
```